# Continued fraction and double series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, continued-fractions

From Euler's continued fraction formula, we have
$$x =
\cfrac{1}{1 - \cfrac{r_1}{1 + r_1 - \cfrac{r_2}{1 + r_2 - \cfrac{r_3}{1 + r_3 - \ddots}}}}\,$$
and
$$x = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty r_1r_2\cdots r_i = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left( \prod_{j=1}^i r_j \right)\,$$
For example:
$$e^z = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\prod_{j=1}^n \frac{z}{j}\right)=$$$$=\cfrac{1}{1 - \cfrac{z}{1 + z - \cfrac{\frac{1}{2}z}{1 + \frac{1}{2}z - \cfrac{\frac{1}{3}z}
{1 + \frac{1}{3}z - \cfrac{\frac{1}{4}z}{1 + \frac{1}{4}z - \ddots}}}}}.\,$$
(by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_continued_fraction_formula#The_exponential_function)).

Well, my question is the following: are there any version of Euler's continued fraction for double series?

Thanks.

Comment: Double series is still just a series (you only need to expand them to see this). So, you can still use Euler's continued fraction for double series as well